# Sbt resource generation in runtime

Tags: sbt

I am trying to achieve what a `resourceGenerator in Runtime` would do: create a resource that is available on the classpath during runtime, however that would not be packaged under the main configuration.

In my specific case, I am trying to create an sbt plugin that facilitates dealing with JNI native libraries. The above mentioned resource would be a "fat" jar containing a shared library, thus it is not required for compilation but only during runtime.
My goal in the end is to publish the standard jar (in the `Compile` configuration) and publish the fat jar as an extra artifact (in the `Runtime` configuration). However, during local testing, I would like the shared libraries to be available on the classpath when simply calling `run` from sbt.

I tried implementing a resourceGenerator in Runtime, however with no success. An alternative approach I could imagine would be to modify `runtime:exportedProducts` or alter `runtime:managedClasspath` directly, however I first wanted to know if there is already a way to include resources only in the runtime configuration?

Comment: customizing `runtime:exportedProducts` seems like the most promising approach to me — what's the downside there?